# Error al reproducir gif en Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy intentando reproducir un gif en una interfaz gráfica, el programa al parecer funciona bien, pero tengo 2 problemas: **Aparecen un montón de errores al cerrar el programa y la reproducción del gif es muy rápida**. Aquí está el código:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageSequence

root = Tk()
root.title("Entrenamiento")
root.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
root.geometry('1000x700+300+50')
root.configure(background='#6dd5ed')

def play_gif():
    img = Image.open("caracal-big.gif")
    lbl = Label(root)
    lbl.place(x=0, y=0)

    for img in ImageSequence.Iterator(img):
        img = img.resize((300,300))
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        lbl.config(image = img)
        root.update()
    root.after(0, play_gif)

btn = Button(root, text= "play", command= play_gif)
btn.place(x=500, y=300)


root.mainloop()
```

Estos son los errores que aparecen al cerrar el programa. Cabe mencionar que aparecen cuando se presiona el botón de "play" y luego se cierra el programa.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyecto Integrador 1er Semestre\reproductor.py", line 38, in play_gif
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4103, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4036, in __init__
    master = _get_default_root('create image')
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 297, in _get_default_root
    raise RuntimeError(f"Too early to {what}: no default root window")
RuntimeError: Too early to create image: no default root window
Exception ignored in: <function PhotoImage.__del__ at 0x000001B9D4525EA0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 146, in __del__
    name = self.__photo.name
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute '_PhotoImage__photo'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No logro replicar el error con exactitud, pero aun así puedo darte una respuesta.

#### Causa del error

El error es causado por que intentas crear la imagen una vez que la instancia de Tk (el conector entre TCL y Python) es destruida. Y como tu bucle for continúa incluso luego de que el interprete deje la existencia, Tkinter se queja al intentar crear la imagen luego.

Si querés saber por que el gif se ejecuta tan rapido, sigue leyendo.

#### Otros errores y sus soluciones

De cualquier modo, tu código tiene algunos errores de concepto y optimización...
Los de optimización pueden hacer que a la larga tu programa consuma muchos recursos.

- Estás creando un nuevo Label cada vez que presionas el botón play. Ten en cuenta que, si reproduces dos o más veces el gif, el label donde hiciste la primera reproducción no dejó de existir. Sigue existiendo, solo que el Label donde aparece la segunda reproducción tapa a este widget no deseado. Y el label de la tercera reproducción tapa al de la primera y segunda. Esto hace que, si el usuario presiona muchas veces el botón, se cree inadvertidamente un montón de Labels.
  La solución aquí es crear un solo Label al inicio del programa, y luego modificarlo para ir poniendo los frames.
- El método after no tiene efecto hasta que termina el bucle for. Lo que hace que se vaya cambiando el frame es método update, que le dice a tkinter "redibuja la ventana". Basicamente, estás pasando de un frame a otro por cada redibujado de la ventana. Por eso se reproduce muy rapido.
  La solución a esto es usar el método after para llamar a una función que cambie el frame dentro de x milisegundos, para que el frame dure lo que deba durar en pantalla.

#### Código mejorado, explicado y funcional

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageSequence
import requests
import io

root = Tk()
root.title("Entrenamiento")
root.resizable(FALSE, FALSE)
root.geometry('1000x700+300+50')
root.configure(background='#6dd5ed')

gif_url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif"

lbl = Label(root)
lbl.place(x=0, y=0)
        
def setframe(iterator, img=None):
    # Si no se pasó el argumento img, obtenemos el frame del
    # siguiente item del iterador de imagenes.
    if(img is None):
        img = next(iterator)
    
    img = img.resize((300,300))
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    lbl.config(image = img)
    # Guardamos una referencia a la imagen en Python para que el
    # recolector de basura no elimine la instancia de PhotoImage.
    lbl.image = img

    # Obtenemos el siguiente frame del iterador. Si el iterador se agotó (esto Python lo avisa con un error llamado StopIteration),
    # es decir, no quedan más frames que mostrar, termina la función sin usar after
    try:
        img = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return

    # Programamos esta misma función para que se ejecute en 50 milisegundos.
    # Y le pasamos de argumentos el iterador y el frame a mostrar.
    root.after(50, setframe, iterator, img)

def start_gif():
    # Esto es un truco para cargar una imagen de la web en una imagen de Pillow.
    # Pero esto requeriría una buena descripción que se iría por las ramas en cuanto a responder tu duda.
    # Podés usar un directorio a una imagen en tu pc en su lugar.
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(gif_url).content))

    iterator = ImageSequence.Iterator(img)

    setframe(iterator)

btn = Button(root, text= "play", command=start_gif)
btn.place(x=500, y=300)
```

Comment: Tienes razón, ya que incluso el código tardaba en ejecutarse. Muchas gracias.